# Facebook Chat client in c# Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, facebook, xmpp, chat

How do I create a client for the facebook chat for windows 7? I know that you have to use a Jabber / XMPP, but sockets are not compatible with wp7, how can I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for the Mango release with (some) socket support.  Your other option would be to have your WP7 app talk to a server that you own, which then brokers the Jabber/ XMPP calls to FaceBook for you.